# How can i use Enter to select item from popup menu?

Tags: plugin-coc, lsp

I am using UltiSnippets

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<None>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<S-b>'
let g:coc_snippet_next = '<tab>'
let g:coc_snippet_prev = '<S-tab>'
```

And also nvim-coc

```
"select from menu by Tab
 inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
       \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
     \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "\<TAB>" :
       \ coc#rpc#request('doKeymap', 'snippets-expand')

 function! s:check_back_space() abort
let col = col('.') - 1
   return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
 endfunction
```

And with tab i can select a item from menu, but when i press Enter to expand snippet or lsp, popup disapear, and expand don't work.

[image]

How can i fix this behavior?

I really like to use tab for navigation throw menu items.
And desactivated UltiSnippets tab expander for this.

Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:help popup-menu-keys` assuming these plugins are using `:help ins-completion-menu`.

You could probably setup a conditional mapping like

```
:inoremap <expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? '<c-y>' : '<cr>'
```

and you could use `<c-y><cr>` instead of just `<c-y>` if you wanted the Enter press to accept and insert a newline.

Comment: Thanks it work like i want.

Comment: @serii Generally we use upvotes or accepted answers for that indicator (see the [help] sections on the relevant topics)